# Errno.13 Permission Denied while trying to access files through HTML and Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

So, I have been trying to learn Flask for a couple of days, and recently I tried to make a simple app that lets you upload a text file and reads the content of the text file. I was able to successfully upload a file, but when I tried to read the file, I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'txt1.txt'
```

(I was trying to read a file called txt1.txt)
Here is my Python Code for it:

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,redirect,url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=["POST","GET","DELETE"])
def home():
    return render_template("ftest.html")
@app.route("/success",methods=["POST","GET","DELETE"])
def success():
if request.method=="POST":
    if request.files:
        f=request.files[ "file"]
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        print(f)
        rd=f.read()
        print(rd)
return "Hi"

if __name__=="__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
   app.run()
```

Here is ftest.html:

```
<html>
<style>
body {
background-color: #8a1e1e ;
}
h1 {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: impact;
font-size: 100px
}
form{
height: 22px;
width: 316px;
background-color: #4C83DC
}
</style>
<head>
<title>Txt Uploader</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Txt Uploader</h1>
<form action = "/success" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type = "submit" value="Upload">

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible solutions

1. Change the permissions of the directory you want to save to so that
   all users have read and write permissions.
2. Make sure the file you are trying to write is closed first. Simply add `rd.close()`
3. If you are using Pycharm. Right-click your PyCharm application and
   run it as administrator.